# ggplot not showing - area is blank

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am relatively new to ggplot2 and I have created a plot based on a csv file.

The problem I am having is that the plot is blank:

[image]

Nothing shows expect the title and I am not sure why!

As you can see the data is fine within RStudio:

[image]

My csv file is in the same directory as my app.R file:

[image]

My working directory is the same folder:

[image]

So why is ggplot2 failing to pick up the data held within the csv file?

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- (fluidPage(
titlePanel("Pig Breeding")
  )
)
mainPanel(
  plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot")
)
server <- (function(input, output){
output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
pig_plot <- ggplot(read.csv("pigs_data.csv"),
          aes_string(x = "species", y = "sow_count")    +
          geom_point())
})
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you passed the plot into `pig_plot` variable . Instead, remove the `pig_plot <-`, and the code should work. Can't test it out as I don't have the file (:

Comment: @javier I have changed the code and removed the area mentioned: 

`server <- (function(input, output){
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(read.csv("pigs_data.csv"),
              aes_string(x = "species", y = "sow_count") +
              geom_point())
    })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)`

However I still get a blank plot area - it's like ggplot ignores my syntax to look at the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below code works with a test data called `iris`. Your mistake lies in your

```
ui <- (fluidPage(
titlePanel("Pig Breeding")
  )
)
mainPanel(
  plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot")
)
```

**ui** code. You have left your `mainPanel` out of the `fluidpage` parenthesis. Thus, it does not read the `plotOutput`.

**Example**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Iris data"),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Petal.Width)) + geom_point()
    })
  }
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The code below should work for your question.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Pig Breeding"),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("scatterplot")
      )
   )

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(read.csv("pigs_data.csv"),
      aes(x = "species", y = "sow_count")) + geom_point()
    })
  }
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```